# the importance of discrete sine transform

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

what are the applications of discrete sine transform . can discrete sine transform be used in place of discrete cosine transform ? please state the reason.

can it be used in compression.?

regards,
phani tej

Comment: It's pretty well explained in this wikipedia article (about the DCT): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#Informal_overview

Answer (score 1):

DCT performs close to KLT so that it is the best choice to compress highly corelated signals. For low correlated signals DST is used , check video coding standards HEVC. Therefore, one is the complement of the other, never a replacement. DCT has the DC component and DST has no DC component